# SQL query to aggregate records based on ID

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, fact-table

is there a way in SQL to at first select records from a table and aggregate it and then insert it into another table? For example, this is the given table.

[**account_id**] | [**job_role_id**] | [**salary**]
               1                       1              10,000

1                       2              10,000

1                       3              10,000

1                       1              20,000

1                       2              10,000

2                       3              10,000

2                       1              20,000

2                      2              20,000

2                      3              10,000

I need to aggregate the records in such a way that all the salary for same job_role_id given by account_id is added in the following way:

[**account_id**] | [**job_role_id**] | [**salary**]
               1                       1              30,000

1                       2              20,000

1                       3              20,000

2                       1              20,000

2                       2              20,000

2                       3              20,000

Excuse my bad English as I am very sleep deprived at this moment and English is my second language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do that first by coming up with your select statement, you want to aggregate the `salary` based on the `account_id` and `job_role_code`. You would do that using the following:

```
SELECT account_id, job_role_id, Sum(salary) as salary
FROM job_table
GROUP BY account_id, job_role_id;
```

The next step is that you want to insert that into some other table to hold this data permanently. We can modify the select like this:

```
INSERT INTO job_salary_aggregate_table (account_id, job_role_id, salary)
SELECT account_id, job_role_id, Sum(salary) as salary
FROM job_table
GROUP BY account_id, job_role_id;
```

This would only be effective to run once. If you need to run it again you would need to truncate the data from the `job_salary_aggregate_table` before attempting to perform the `SELECT INTO...` again.

As requested, additional count:

```
INSERT INTO job_salary_aggregate_table (account_id, job_role_id, salary, num_agged)
SELECT account_id, job_role_id, Sum(salary) as salary, Count(1) as num_agged
FROM job_table
GROUP BY account_id, job_role_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, is there a way to display the number of records being aggregated in a new column? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, add a `Count(1) as num_agged`. I will modify my answer to include that in an additional query.

Comment: Thank you very much. Ill be able to go to sleep after this haha.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a `GROUP BY` here.

```
SELECT account_id, job_role_id, SUM(salary)
FROM jobs
GROUP BY account_id, job_role_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.